# How does Raven DB SQL Replication handle saving arrays to SQL?

Tags: sql, ravendb, database-replication

I am currently setting up SQL Replication to replicate our Raven DB documents into SQL for reporting purposes. So far everything has been working great. However, I am now trying to save a document that contains an array for days of the week.

This is how the document looks in Raven:

```json
{
  "ClientId": "clients/385",
  "Description": "Test",
  "IsOneOff": false,
  "RecursEveryWeeks": 1,
  "StartDate": "2013-03-19T00:00:00.0000000",
  "TaskStartTime": "12:00:00",
  "TaskDuration": 120,
  "TaskEndTime": "14:00:00",
  "AdditionalResources": false,
  "AdditionalVisitType": "TestType",
  "BillableTo": "Private",
  "RecurrenceEndDate": "2013-04-30T00:00:00.0000000",
  "DaysOfWeek": [
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday"
  ]
}
```

In SQL Replication I have done the following:

```js
sqlReplicate("AdditionalVisit", "AdditionalVisitId", {
       ClientId: this.ClientId,
       Description: this.Description,
       IsOneOff: this.IsOneOff,
       RecursEveryWeeks: this.RecursEveryWeeks,
       StartDate: this.StartDate,
       TaskStartTime: this.TaskStartTime,
       TaskDuration: this.TaskDuration,
       TaskEndTime: this.TaskEndTime,
       AdditionalResources: this.AdditionalResources,
       AdditionalVisitType: this.AdditionalVisitType,
       BillableTo: this.BillableTo,
       RecurrenceEndDate: this.RecurrenceEndDate,
       DaysOfWeek: this.DaysOfWeek
});
```

All of this works fine when I leave DaysOfWeek out of the SQL Replication but causes the server to crash when I leave in.

How should this be done in SQL Replication so everything in the array is saved to a DaysOfWeek column in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tested this, but it's along the lines of what you want...just add this to the end of your current script.

```js
for (var i=0; i<this.DaysOfWeek.length; i++) {
    var day = this.DaysOfWeek[i];
    sqlReplicate('AdditionalVisit_DaysOfWeek', 'AdditionalVisitId', {
        AdditionalVisitId: documentId,
        DayOfWeek: day,
    });
}
```

By the way there is currently a bug in the SqlReplication for RavenDb 2.1 where deletes won't be pushed through to SqlReplication, it's supposed to be fixed in 2.5 branch but there are still some other issues that need to be worked on for it to become usable.